# Draggable Parent but Keep Child Scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When calling draggable on a parent div, I am no longer able to scroll the child div on mobile devices. When the child div is touched, I would like the div to be scrolled, but let the parent remain undragged.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.table').draggable()
});
```

```css
.table
{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 15px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.table-lower
{
  overflow-y:auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
<p>TABLE NAME</p>
<div class="table-lower">
<p>This is the part that I want scrollable on mobile; dont' trigger draggable here on touch</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tincidunt iaculis aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec scelerisque imperdiet ullamcorper. Etiam sit amet ornare leo, malesuada elementum nibh. Nulla in malesuada est, nec accumsan lorem. Vivamus eget sodales sapien. Donec non nibh nisl. Aenean vitae ipsum eu tortor ultrices vulputate. Suspendisse commodo pretium metus, non lacinia metus ultricies at. Duis ut euismod tortor, in feugiat metus. Nullam condimentum nisl nisi, sit amet dictum metus mollis quis. Phasellus et lectus a lacus ornare convallis.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a class to the title `p` element and use it has a [`handle`](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle). This will ensure that the drags can happen from the title element, and not from every child of the `.table` element.

Working demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.table').draggable({
    handle: 'p.handle'
  })
});
```

```css
.table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-lower {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <p class="handle">TABLE NAME</p>
  <div class="table-lower">
    <p>This is the part that I want scrollable on mobile; dont' trigger draggable here on touch</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tincidunt iaculis aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec scelerisque imperdiet ullamcorper. Etiam sit amet ornare leo, malesuada
      elementum nibh. Nulla in malesuada est, nec accumsan lorem. Vivamus eget sodales sapien. Donec non nibh nisl. Aenean vitae ipsum eu tortor ultrices vulputate. Suspendisse commodo pretium metus, non lacinia metus ultricies at. Duis ut euismod tortor,
      in feugiat metus. Nullam condimentum nisl nisi, sit amet dictum metus mollis quis. Phasellus et lectus a lacus ornare convallis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```